# Visual Studio 2008 on Vista problems

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-vista

Does anyone have any problems with VS2008 on Vista?
For me every so often when I select items in the solution explorer the screen goes blank. No other application causes this to happen.

Comment: I haven't seen this behavior, though sometimes it hangs for a while and the IDE is showing (not responsing).

Comment: That's very typical behaviour in Visual studio 2005 too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of our guys had this problem. For some odd reason, check to see if your video drivers are up to date.

Comment: You are right, this is completely related to the video card / drivers.

Comment: Yup - I've just updated the Display adapters drivers (for me Radeon X1650 SE) and this has got it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I originally had some issues with Visual Studio 2008 and Vista but not the type of problem you describe. Everything seemed to work fine once I installed the Vista compatibility updates. I would think that the latest SP would take care of this as well.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. However I've installed sp1 but its made no difference.